# URLLoader annoying problem

Tags: flash, cs3

i am trying to load a variable through php from a sql database but i get nothing

here is the code

```
var Idfield;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
// data will come as URL encoded variables
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.load(new URLRequest("pull.php"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,dataload);                                     
function dataload(e:Event){
    Idfield =e.target.data["id"];
    trace(Idfield);
}
```

here is the php code

```
   $query = "SELECT max(id) from $tablename";
    $result = mysql_query($query) 
        or die("no rows selected");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); // extracts one row
    echo  "id=$row[0]";
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the variables format expects the variables in the name=value format so try something like:

```
echo 'id=' . $row[0];
```

Comment: Yea, you're right.  That should have been a . for concatenation. Let me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

well for one thing, you need to add your event listener before you actually call load().

When you say you get nothing, what do you mean?

you can also listen for an error event and dump out any error messages from there.

HTH

Comment: if i only use 
     Idfield =e.target.data;

if get the whole php when i do the trace

Comment: what do you mean you get the whole php? The script? The output of the script?  We really need you to be more specific to be of much help.

Comment: sorry about that.. i get he whole php script back when i do the trace

but if i try Idfield =e.target.data["id"];  i get nothing back

Comment: if you are getting the script itself back, meaning the code, then that means that your php script is not being executed...

If you browse to that script itself in your web-browser, what do you get?

Comment: i actually get the value.. its only through flash that am not getting anything back

Comment: i got it after changing  echo  "id=$row[0]";  thanks for the help though